# Trying to put DQL query into Highcharts array, returns 0 despite array being populated

Tags: php, symfony, highcharts, bundle, dql

Here is the var_dump for my query in my code:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'barbell_curl_1_weight' => int 15
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'barbell_curl_1_weight' => int 20
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'barbell_curl_1_weight' => int 25
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'barbell_curl_1_weight' => int 20
```

Here's my query:

```
/**
 * @param User $user
 * @param String $col
 * @return array
 */
public function getStatsForStatsByDQL(User $user,  String $col)
{

    $parameters = (array('user' => $user,
    ));
    $em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:ExerciseStats')
        ->createQueryBuilder('g')
        ->setParameters($parameters)
        ->where('g.user = :user')
        ->select('g.'. $col)
        ->setMaxResults(12)
        ->join('g.user', 'user')
        ->orderBy( 'g.'. 'timestamp','ASC')
        ->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    return $em2;
  }
```

As you see from the var_dump, I'm getting the data I need back. Here's the  Highcharts function it goes in:

```
/**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @Route ("user/stats", name="user_stats")
 */
public function chartAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    // Chart
    $query = $this->getStatsForStatsByDQL($user, 
ExerciseConsts::BARBELL_CURL_1_WEIGHT);


    $series = array($query, array("name" => "weight", "data" => 
$query));

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('linechart');  
    $ob->title->text('Barbell Curl Weight');
    $ob->xAxis->title(array('text'  => "Workouts"));
    $ob->yAxis->title(array('text'  => "Weight"));
    $ob->series($series);

    return $this->render('user/stats.html.twig', array(
        'chart' => $ob
    ));
}
```

So all I'm getting back is 0. When using breakpoints in xdebug, I get back this:

```
1 = {array} [2]
  name = "weight"
  data = {array} [4]
  0 = {array} [1]
    barbell_curl_1_weight = 15
  1 = {array} [1]
    barbell_curl_1_weight = 20
  2 = {array} [1]
    barbell_curl_1_weight = 25
  3 = {array} [1]
    barbell_curl_1_weight = 20
```

How do I extract the weights and get it into the Highchart graph? Documentation for the Highcharts Bundle is completely lacking in this regard. Let me know if anyone has any clues. Thanks!

Here's the var_dump of json_encode($series, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK). Maybe this will help:

string '[[{"barbell_curl_1_weight":15},{"barbell_curl_1_weight":20},{"barbell_curl_1_weight":25},{"barbell_curl_1_weight":20}],{"name":"weight","data":[{"barbell_curl_1_weight":15},{"barbell_curl_1_weight":20},{"barbell_curl_1_weight":25},{"barbell_curl_1_weight":20}]}]' (length=266)

Comment: you can use `$ob=json_encode($ob,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` and then pass to series

Comment: I am not quite following. I already have $ob = new Highchart(). How exactly would this work? If you could clarify a little, that'd be great. Thanks for your time.

Comment: my mistake , it should be `$series=json_encode($series,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: All right, but then where does the $query go? Since $series is now replaced with json_encode.

Comment: remove `json_encode` and let me know what is coming in front end ie(html) inside script for highcharts, you can use https://pastebin.com/ for this

Comment: In my twig file, all I have is <div id="linechart" style="..."></div>. What it is outputting in the html.twig is a blank graph with a value of 0 for each array value (0, 1, 2, 3 being the array values). I have no data on the the JS is doing except what is in the console. Which doesn't seem super informative. There are no errors being thrown by JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146022/discussion-between-deep-3015-and-bill-wagner).

Comment: I've got to go to bed, I just realized you suggested using pastebin. If you think it'll help, I'll use it to paste in the console output when I get up tomorrow. Thanks for the help. Good nite.

Comment: Could you paste how your series output does it look like (as JSON) ? I will verify the structure

Comment: I posted a var_dump of the json_encode output, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As we are dealing with a multi-dimensional array, Highcharts is not drilling down beyond the first array, which returns 0. Here's my iteration to return the values of each array:

```
 $temp = array();
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            foreach($v as $key=>$value){
                $temp[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

So now, I just need to replace   $temp with $query and voila', the chart is rendered with all values correctly.